# I'm getting `GET http://localhost:4567/my_app.dart.js 404 (Not Found) ` in Chrome, but works fine in Dartium

Tags: dart, dartium

I'm trying to get my dummy Dart webapp running in browsers. Here's the code of my html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
    <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='button'>hello world</div>
  </body>
  <script src='my_app.dart' type='application/dart'></script>
  <script src='packages/browser/dart.js'></script>
</html>
```

and this is what I'm getting in js console when trying to open it:

```
GET http://localhost:4567/my_app.dart.js 404 (Not Found)
```

(I'm running it on a local server, thus the url - got the same error if simply opening an html file though).

If I open the same url in Dartium, the webapp works. So the problem, I suppose, is that `dart.js` doesn't work as expected. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that running Dart programs in non Dartium browsers requires to compile to Javascript first (see the js file extension). But the dev server should do it automaticly - but you can do it manualy too. What dev server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`packages/browser/dart.js` is a bootstrap script that checks if a Dart VM is available on your browser. If a Dart VM is available, your dart script is executed directly, otherwise `packages/browser/dart.js` appends to the document a new js script with a url that points to a file with the same name as your dart file but with a appended `.js`. Depending on how you work you may have to generate this JS file manually with [dart2js](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html) :

```
dart2js --out=my_app.dart.js my_app.dart
```

Comment: Oh that explains it. So it's NOT like Dart can generate javascript out of my .dart file on the fly, every time I reload a page, right?

Comment: It depends on your working style. If you use the Dart Editor "Run as Javascript" should do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Run as Java Script" it should generate additional files like "my_app.dart.js"